# Unable to send email using SMTP on server

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I am using smtp client to send email, but problem is that when i tried to send email form my local system email successfully sent but i deployed on server than email not sent. Here is my code

```
 try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(receiver);
            mail.From = new MailAddress("lms.mannconsultant@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            if (attachment != null)
            {
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling access to less secure apps on your google account?

Comment: Yes, its enabled.

Comment: If you can send email from your local system using same code and unable to send it from server then it seems like problem doesn't lie in your code. May be problem is in how you call methods on your server or how your server connects to internet(firewall issues maybe).

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for that.By looking at your code i suggest first you verify weather any exception is generated when this code executes in server(log exception).This will help to investigate further.Also check port(587) you are using in code is not blocked by server firewall(if enabled in server.)